# Adding count Column From SQL Query TO data fram In Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny

I have R script which calculate the ratio of getting every pair products at one order and i created a shiny app to view my result [My App](https://abdalmoamen95.shinyapps.io/CorrelationApp/) 
and this's my server code

```
server <- function(input,output){
  data<- reactive({
    DF %>% filter(FirstItem == input$Item, X.Correlation > 0, SecondItem != input$Item) %>% arrange(desc(X.Correlation))
  })

  output$Itemcorr <- renderTable({data()})

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    barplot(data()$X.Correlation,main="X.Correlation Distribution", 
            xlab="SecondItems",ylab="Percent",xlim=c(1,60),ylim = c(0,100),
            col=c("darkblue","red"),names.arg =data()$SecondItem)

  })

}
```

but i want to add another column in my app which view the number of orders of( **SecondItem** * (**X.Correlation**/100)). i tried to do that using cbind to do that

```
 renderTable({cbind(data(),(data()$X.Correlation/100)*dbGetQuery(con,"SELECT
 Count(WHWorkOrderHeaderId) FROM   Warehouse.WHWorkOrderDetails  INNER
 JOIN Warehouse.WHWorkOrderHeader AS WHH ON
 Warehouse.WHWorkOrderDetails.WHWorkOrderHeaderId = WHH.ID  INNER JOIN
 Warehouse.StockItems  ON Warehouse.WHWorkOrderDetails.StockItemId =
 Warehouse.StockItems.Id  WHERE Type = 'IO' AND OtherLangDescription =
 data()$SecondItem ORDER BY OtherLangDescription ASC"))})
```

but i cant call sql query depending on the in R

Comment: hello, try this:

`data<- reactive({
    DF %>% filter(FirstItem == input$Item, X.Correlation > 0, SecondItem != input$Item) %>% arrange(desc(X.Correlation)) %>% mutate(new_column_name = new_column_data)
  })´

Comment: Are you mean to put the count sql statement in the  **new_column_data** field ?

Comment: I assumed that you are working with a dataframe. Aren't you?

Comment: Yes i am, But this dataframe doesn't has the count column so i want to get it from my data in sql server

Comment: If a key exists in both dataframe you can use join / merge or even mutate with if/else condition

Comment: Yes of course the column **SecondItem** Has the same values in **OtherLangDescription**  in my select but how to join with foreign column in sql ?

Comment: `OtherLangDescription =
 data()$SecondItem`

Comment: Make another sqlquery and merge both dataframes :S. I dont understand your need to work in sql and not in R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved that by defining new Data-frame having the values of the SQL query and then i merged it with the existing DF:

```
OrdersNum <- dbGetQuery(con, "
SELECT
OtherLangDescription ,
Count(WHWorkOrderHeaderId) AS Orders_Of_SecondItem
FROM   Warehouse.WHWorkOrderDetails 
INNER JOIN Warehouse.WHWorkOrderHeader AS WHH
ON Warehouse.WHWorkOrderDetails.WHWorkOrderHeaderId = WHH.ID 
INNER JOIN Warehouse.StockItems 
ON Warehouse.WHWorkOrderDetails.StockItemId = Warehouse.StockItems.Id 
WHERE Type = 'IO'
GROUP By OtherLangDescription
ORDER BY OtherLangDescription ASC")

DF1 <- merge(DF, OrdersNum, by.x = "SecondItem", by.y = "OtherLangDescription")
DF<-DF1[,c(2,1,3,4)]
```